# How can I specify a custom display resolution on Fedora 35 (GNOME Wayland)?

Tags: fedora, screen-resolution, gnome, wayland

How can I specify a custom display resolution on Fedora 35 (GNOME Wayland)? I've tried changing Displays > Resolution, but the maximum resolution available is 1920x1080 (16:9). I would like to set the resolution to 2560x1080 (21:9).